# Why do i get three different methods to calculate the same current ,but get three different current values?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current

I want to find the current \$I_R\$,and i used three methods,and i got three different 
\$I_R\$ values,i hope someone can tell me where am i wrong!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFnVNt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

method 1 & 2  : There are  two circuits  as below,the main difference between them is the direction of \$I_2\$,which are opposite!

Left hand circuit :

\$I_R=I_1=3\frac{(2+3)}{(2+3)+(1+R_L)}=3\frac{5}{6+R_L}=\frac{15}{6+R_L}\$

Right hand circuit :

\$I_R=I_1=3+I_2=3+1\frac{3}{3+(2+1+R_L)}=3+\frac{3}{6+R_L}=\frac{21+3R_L}{6+R_L}\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSkS1y.png)</sup>

method 3:superposition

\$I_R=I_{R1}+I_{R2}+I_{R3}=0+[3\frac{(2+3)}{(2+3)+(1+R_L)}]+[1\frac{3}{3+(2+1+R_L)}]=\frac{18}{6+R_L}\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftxYoQ.png)</sup>

If we use the maximum power Maximum Power Transfer Theorem,we can know \$R_L=6Ω\$.However,now i have a big problem,that is,we can see that when i  replace \$R_L\$ with \$6Ω\$ in the current from method 1 to method 2,we can find that we have three different \$I_R\$ values!!

I believe that  \$I_R\$ value by using method 3 is correct,but i don't know where am i wrong in my method 1 and method 2,can anyone tell me the mistake i made?

Comment: You should add units to your equations. The assumption \$I_R=I_1=3A \frac{(2 \Omega+3\Omega)}{(2\Omega+3\Omega)+(1\Omega+R_L)}\$ is incorrect. The current of 3A isn't divided across R3,R2, R4 and RL like that, because it does not take into account the contribution of the 1A current.

Comment: *You should add units to your equations* that will help as a "sanity check" so that you'll notice when you're making a mistake and trying to add a voltage to a current for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 3 is correct.**

\$I_R=I_{R1}+I_{R2}+I_{R3}=\color{orange}{0\text{ A }}+\color{magenta}{[3\text{ A }\frac{(2\Omega+3\Omega)}{(2\Omega+3\Omega)+(1\Omega+R_L)}]} +\color{blue}{[1\text{ A }\frac{3\Omega}{3\Omega+(2\Omega+1\Omega+R_L)}] } =\frac{18\Omega}{6\Omega+R_L}\text{ A}\$

That method also shows what goes wrong in method 1 and 2:

**In the Left hand circuit:**

\$I_R=I_1=3 \text{ A } \frac{(2\Omega+3\Omega)}{(2\Omega+3\Omega)+(1\Omega+R_L)}\$

The current of 3A isn't divided across \$R_3\$, \$R_2\$, \$R_4\$ and \$R_L\$ like that, because it does not take into account the contribution of the 1A current.

You can see it comparing it to the solution of method 3: Only the contribution of the 3A current source (magenta part) is taken into account by this method 1, not the contribution of the 1A current source (blue part).

**Right hand circuit:**

\$I_R=I_1=3\text{ A }+I_2=3\text{ A }+1\text{ A }\frac{3\Omega}{3\Omega+(2\Omega+1\Omega+R_L)}\$

The problem here is that the 3A current is not only running through \$R_9\$ and \$R_L\$, but **also** through \$R_8\$ and \$R_7\$.

Comparing to method 3 you can see that only \$ \frac{(2\Omega+3\Omega)}{(2\Omega+3\Omega)+(1\Omega+R_L)}\$ part of the 3A current flow through \$R_L\$.

---

Regarding method 1 correct approach would be:

Using the left hand circuit:

The voltage across \$R_2\$ is given by \$V_{R_2}= (i_2+1\text{ A }) \cdot R_2 \$
The voltage across \$R_3\$ is given by \$V_{R_3}=i_2 \cdot  R_3 \$

The sum of these voltages is across \$R_1\$ and \$R_L\$, so the current through \$R_L\$ is given by 
$$ i_{R_L} = \frac{ V_{R_2}+V_{R_3} }{R_1+R_L} = \frac{ (i_2+1\text{ A }) \cdot R_2 + i_2 \cdot  R_3 }{R_1+R_L}$$

According KCL, \$i_2+i_{R_L}=3\text{ A }\$. Substituting for \$i_2\$ this yields

$$ i_{R_L} = \frac{ (3\text{ A }-i_{R_L} +1\text{ A }) \cdot R_2 + (3\text{ A }-i_{R_L}) \cdot  R_3 }{R_1+R_L}$$

$$ i_{R_L} (R_1+R_L) =  4\text{ A } \cdot R_2 - i_{R_L} \cdot R_2 + 3\text{ A } \cdot  R_3 - i_{R_L}\cdot  R_3 $$

$$ i_{R_L} (R_1+R_2+R_3+R_L) =  4\text{ A } \cdot R_2 + 3\text{ A } \cdot  R_3 $$

$$ i_{R_L} =  \frac{ 4\text{ A } \cdot R_2  + 3\text{ A } \cdot  R_3 }{R_1+R_2+R_3+R_L} $$